# Which coords fall into my grid

Tags: raster, r, maps, terra

I have data of locations, co-ordinates, and covariate values associated. I want to aggregate multiple locations into grids and then calculate the mean sum of covariates in each grid. I importantly want to know which locations are falling into each grid cell.

```
west_nile_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = west_nile_coords[, c("lon", "lat")],
                                   data = west_nile_coords,
                                   proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Set the desired grid size for visualization and aggregation
grid_size <- 2 # Adjust this value to match your desired grid size

raster_grid <- raster(ext = extent(west_nile_sp), res = grid_size)

# Create a raster grid based on the extent of the points
raster_grid <- raster(ext = extent(west_nile_sp), res = grid_size)
grid_assign <- rasterize(west_nile_sp, raster_grid, field = west_nile_data$branch_length)
```

Comment: Some tips: try and make examples that run from the code you post - use sample data from packages or generate in code; show the packages you use - its not clear if this is using `raster`, `terra` or both; stop using the `sp` package and use the `sf` package for vector data (points, lines polygons) and also stop using `raster` for rasters and use `terra` - the older packages are deprecated and will disappear soon.